# TextField clickable if it is not null

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, textfield

sorry to ask a stupid question but I really do not know how to solve. I have one textView and I want it to be clickable if it is not null. How can I do to achieve this?

```
 c = (TextView) claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
 c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                 {
            if(c!=null)

            {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Receipt.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            }
            });
```

**Error:**

```
    Error:(137, 13)  error: illegal start of type
    Error:(137, 17) error: <identifier> expected
    Error:(137, 19) error: ';' expected
    Error:(140, 26) error: ';' expected
    Error:(146, 14) error: ')' expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write this code:

```
  c = (TextView) claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
  if (c != null) {
            c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (View v){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Receipt.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is improper closure of braces...but it is not correct way to check null pointer after applying setOnClickListener **so change the code to**

```
c = (TextView) claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49); 

if(null != c){  
  c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override           
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Receipt.class);
                 startActivity(intent);             }

            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
if(!textViewn.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
    }
```